# Sessions not working on local GAE project in IntelliJ

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I have a Google App Engine webapp that uses sessions.  When I deploy it to the cloud, it works fine.  When I run it locally in the debugger using IntelliJ's built-in server, sessions are not working.  If I look at the requests in Chrome's network debugger, it appears that a new session cookie is being sent each time.

In particular, it appears that the JSESSION cookie is not being saved, even though I see it in the response.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: have u enabled session in Appengine-web.xml?

Comment: yes, it works on GAE just not locally.  Also, if I connect from a web server on the same port, it works, but not from a different port.  (e.g., app-engine is running on localhost:8080.  I get the session cookie when I connect from a web site also on 8080 but not if I run it on a different port.)